# About veracity of a logic

Tags: logic

Prove that the sentence
$∃x∀y∃z((P(y, z) ⇒ P(x, z)) ⇒ (P(x, x) ⇒ P(y, x))) $

is true in all finite structures but is false in a certain infinite structure (P is
a binary predicate, x, y, z are variables)

I dont know how to proced in this case. How to prove that is a tautology. Maybe with a hint, I dont know how to proced in the case of general predicate.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Think of some ordering relationship, like smaller or greater than.

Also, it may be useful to recognize that $∃x∀y∃z((P(y, z) ⇒ P(x, z)) ⇒ (P(x, x) ⇒ P(y, x))) $ is equivalent to $∃x∀y(∀z(P(y, z) ⇒ P(x, z)) ⇒ (P(x, x) ⇒ P(y, x))) $

Comment: Okey its saying that if u have an order its saying that if you choose a constant in a certain structure and then you can find always a constant such that for every y, then u can find a x between y and z, but in particular for y=x this sentence is $(∀z(P(x,z)⇒P(x,z))⇒(P(x,x)⇒P(x,x)))$ and this is a Tautology I think. Am I right?

Comment: You can't just look at the $y=x$ case since for any x you need to consider all possible y's. Indeed, if what you are saying is true, then there would be no difference between finite and infinite structures.

Comment: Then how can I do the prove, in the abstract sense I cant see it

Comment: It is not a tautology, since there is an infinite structure for which it is false. So you won't be able to formally prove it.  What you need to do is to consider what it would take for the statement to be false, i.e. in what kind of structure the statement is false. When you do this, you should find that apparently you need an infinite number of objects.

Comment: I can not see how to beggin, this Predicate is refering a maximal number or what? I dont know I can not see how to proceed in that case, I need more hints